# Fixed Sidebar with Fixed Header and Scrollable Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I'm looking to have a fixed sidebar that works on mobile with a fixed header and a scrollable content section. I'd like to have the sidebar itself fill 100% of the view height, but be a certain % of the overall screen width.

I have a solution with 100vh that works on desktop, but on mobile the bottom 'navigation' links of the browser overlap the content.

Is there a known solution to make this work? At this point, I don't care if I have to use JavaScript to make it work right.

Comment: add the code your are working with at the moment to the question to make it better understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem with your current sidebar styling is that it overlaps bottom nav links on mobile devices, you can address that with a media query:

```css
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar 
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 160px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style page content */
.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidebar (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
/* Style the header */
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the header gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<!-- Page content -->
<div class="main">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent.

Tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque. Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat. Ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero. Libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt.

Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. At erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Feugiat nisl pretium fusce id. Tortor dignissim convallis aenean et. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique.

Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. A diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. Et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem.

Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem. Suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.

Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed. Neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum.

Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum.

Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi. Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie. Donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id.

Ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio. Risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis.

Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel. Leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis.
</div>
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp